# Probability that the first two and last two jellybeans agree in colors

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> A child has a jar of 6 red and 10 blue jellybeans. The child wants to
> eat 4 jellybeans, so they grab 4 jellybeans one-by-one uniformly at
> random without replacement from the jar. Find the probability that the
> first two and last two jellybeans agree in colors (not necessarily in
> order). For example, RBBR and RRRR are both valid, but RRBR is not.

So the valid options are:

RRRR, BBBB,

RBRB, RBBR, BRRB, BRBR

There are $C(10,4)+C(6,4)$ ways to choose one of RRRR, BBBB.

We can choose two R and two B in $C(10,2)C(6,2)$ ways. Then I suppose we need to multiply this by the number of ways to order them? I don't exactly understand what we should multiply this by. Should it be $2!2!$?

The final answer will be $$\frac{??? +C(10,4)+C(6,4)}{C(16,4)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way. Draw two at a time. The number of ways for the first pair is $\binom{16}{2}$, and the number of ways for the second pair is $\binom{14}{2}$. The total number of possibilities is therefore $\binom{16}{2} \binom{14}{2}$.

Now to count the successful ways, we can consider a few cases. The first is (RR, RR), which happens in $\binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2}$ ways. Another is (BB, BB), which happens in $\binom{10}{2} \binom{8}{2}$ ways. The final is (RB, RB), which happens in $(6) (10) (5) (9)$ ways.

The desired probability is therefore

$$P = \frac{\binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2} + \binom{10}{2} \binom{8}{2} + (6) (10) (5) (9)}{\binom{16}{2} \binom{14}{2}} = \boxed{\frac{135}{364}}$$

It is harder working with a sample space of $\binom{16}{4}$, as you have done, because we can't distinguish the two pairs that are drawn.